# PayPal Sandbox Button giving me an error

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to test out my PayPal IPN with sandbox.paypal.com. I have my paypal-generated button on my website, and I modified the URL it posts to by adding sandbox in front of paypal.com.

However, every time I click the button, I get this error:

PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website.

I setup a sandbox account on developer.paypal.com, I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: Please add your code!

Comment: Yes, as he said, please include the code of what you're sending to us. We can take a look then. Thanks!